# How to open SMB share from terminal in mac 10.4?

Tags: macos

I have an API which opens SMB share in MAC OS. The SMB URL i use look like `"smb://username:password@host/folderlocation"` . This works good in the latest Mac versions and doesn't work in MAC 10.4. I have no luck trying outside the API by providing URL in the terminal of MAC. How do i resolve this problem ? Help would be appreciated.

Regards

G Samrat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I used apple script to open the samba file location.